# Conditional in SASS mixin throws error

Tags: sass, mixins

I'm trying to create a mixin using conditionals but I'm getting an error at compile time. The error being generated is:

```
Error: Properties are only allowed within rules, directives, mixin includes, or other properties.
```

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
@mixin mypadder ($topBottomBoth: myDefaultOption, $topUnits: 0, $bottomUnits: 0) {
    @if $topBottomBoth == tp {
        padding-top: 1em;
        }
    @else if $topBottomBoth == bt {
        padding-bottom: 1em;
        }
    @else {
        padding-top: 1em;
        padding-bottom: 1em;
        }
    }
```

I've also tried putting the value of the $topBottomBoth parameter in quotes, firstly just where it appears in the parameters (first line of the mixin) and then additionally putting quotes around the values of that variable/parameter in the conditional tests. In every case I get the same error. Having looked at numerous examples of conditional mixins I still cannot see where my syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your mixin, you're just calling it wrong.  Sass knows that CSS properties are not allowed outside of selectors.

Incorrect:

```
@include mypadder;
```

Correct:

```
.foo {
    @include mypadder;
}
```

Comment: Agh! How did I miss that? I've been placing @includes non-stop for days, so I can't even plead "I don't know how to use mixins". You know how you somehow can't see the wood for the trees…
 
Good to know that my basic mixin was correct though. Cheers.